# Looking for a way to sort data by key in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, mongodb, sorting, aggregation-framework

I was trying to use GET request to get data from MongoDB, but the order of data is changed every time I refresh the URL. I used the `$sort` method in MongoDB, but the order is still changed.

```
let apiURL_1 = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/Mydata');
```

My data:

```
[{"Bread":6},{"Fruit":6},{"Cholate":4}]
```

Expected Output (alphabet order) either using `$sort`aggregation from MongoDB or doing some javascript to sort data.

```
[{"Bread":6}, {"Cholate":4}, {"Fruit":6}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this aggregation query:

- First create a field called `root` using `$objectToArray`
- Then, the keys are in a field called `k`, so you can sort by that field.
- And last remove the auxiliar field created previously.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$set": {
      "root": {
        "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "root.k": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "root": 0
    }
  }
])
```

Example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CTweKAPzubz)